# how can I use an alternative of this code? Im trying to give a different number from my database to each user visiting my page

Tags: php, html, database

is there any better way than this? sure it is but i dont know how.
Im trying to distribute some numbers from my database to each user(host) visiting my page. one number
(item) per visit.
all i came up with is some primitive way. im asking if there is any faster or shorter way than this?
keep in mind that i dont want to use cockies or register the user. the numbers are saved as a string in a column only.

```
<?php
  include_once 'includes/conn.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>VeniVidiVici</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php

    $query = "SELECT numero FROM potluck LIMIT 1;"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo $resultCheck ."<br>";
    if ($resultCheck > 0){ 
      $row= mysqli_fetch_row($result);
      echo $row['0'];
      $del = "DELETE FROM potluck LIMIT 1;";
      mysqli_query($conn, $del); 
      
       }        
?>      
        
    </body>
</html>
```

i dont the users getting the same number and when the database finishes all the rows i want to stop serving the numbers.
numbers in the database are unique.

```
numero
11-12-13
13-14-17
23-45-55
```

ps: the code works i just need an alternative solution instead of deleting my rows in database and replacing each day with a new table.

Comment: So you're trying to serve a limited number of users, you want to give each user a number, and when you're out of numbers you want to stop accepting users, is that right ?

Comment: the user may visit the page but will be no more numbers.  the page later will display numbers in the list finished.

Comment: come back tomorrow :)